# C++, Template vs Auto vs Any

Tags: c++, templates, auto, any

I'm working for my library, and i must generalize some functions, that is, these functions need to handle different types of data passed as parameters.

ex:

```
   Class myClass
   { 
     public:
       int num;
       char mark;
       vector <bool> boolVector;
   }

    myClass cl;

    void myFunction(any/auto/T value, int operation)
    {
      switch(operation)
      {
        case A:
        { 
           cl.num = value; break;
        } 
        
        case B:
        {
           cl.mark = value; break;
        }
        
        case C:
        {
          for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
             cl.vector.at(i) = value[i];
          } 
          
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm undecided on what to use between:

- any,
- some
- template

obviously, this is a very trivial example, while the real functions in my code process this data more complicatedly

So:

1. who is the fastest?
2. Who uses the most memory?
3. Who is the most used?
4. Which do you prefer and why?

Comment: Just write 3 functions to set each member. Or use the `std::tuple` interface.

Comment: None of your propositions will work with code you wrote. And as above commenter, I'd probably use different functions rather than random `int` to select which member is to be set.

Comment: I wonder how many versions it’s gonna be before the committee convinces itself that `constexpr switch` is a good idea….

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR You should probably re-think your design

None of `auto`, a template parameter, or `std::any` really work for your function as written.

In this context, `auto` and a template type parameter are the same thing.
That is

```
void foo(auto value)
{
    // ...
}
```

is just shorthand for

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Since they're both templates, they are resolved at compile time.  That is `foo(some_int)` and `foo(some_char)` end up calling *different* functions `foo<int>` and `foo<char>` that the compiler generates from the template that you wrote.  As such, there's no runtime performance overhead (aside from possibly increased executable size).  It also means the compiler can do type-checking to ensure you're not trying to do something with an object that it can't do.  That means that whatever type is given as the parameter must be valid in all branches of the function; even if they'll never be taken for a given type of parameter at runtime.

---

`std::any` is something entirely different.  `std::any` is a type-erased wrapper class that can hold objects of any type.  Additionally, a given `std::any` object can change from holding one type to another over the course of its lifetime.  That means that the compiler cannot do any type checking for you if you use `std::any`.  Type checking can only be done at runtime, which means `std::any` is fairly cumbersome to use and has some runtime performance overhead.  It has its uses, but they're fairly few and far between.

---

If you can, you should probably split your function into multiple.  For instance:

```
void myFunctionA(int num)
{
    cl.num = num;
}

void myFunctionB(char mark)
{
    cl.mark = mark;
}

void myFunctionC(std::vector<bool> boolVector)
{
    cl.boolVector = boolVector;
}
```

(Note, be wary of `std::vector<bool>`, it isn't a real container and behaves strangely in some situations).